# show link when one div is mousemoving by jquery css

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show two links when the user move the mouse over one div and hide them when the user leave the div  then , I do this  : [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/c6AnE/5/)

```
    <div id="mydiv"  style="background-color : red;width:100px;height:100px;position: relative;" >
<div id="subdiv1" style="position: absolute;" >
<a href="#" style="color:red;" >link 1</a>
</br><a href="#" style="color:red;" >link 2</a>
</div>
<div id="subdiv2" style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color : blue;" ></div
</div>
```

but no result

How can I achieve this

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this JavaScript:

```
$('#subdiv1').hide();
$('#subdiv2').mouseover(function(){
    $('#subdiv1').show();
});
$('#subdiv2').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#subdiv1').hide();
});
```

Comment: No, I've changed `#subdi` to `#subdiv` and `mouseenter` to `mouseover`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want smth like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/c6AnE/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <a href="#">#1 link</a>
    <a href="#">#2 link</a>
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#two").mouseenter(function(){
      $("#one").hide();
    });
$("#two").mouseleave(function(){
      $("#one").show();
    });
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
#two {
    position:absoluite;
    margin-left:30px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
```